# Why is my loss so high and accuracy stays at 0.1?

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am new to deep learning and neural network so I need help understanding why this is happening and how i can fix it.
I have a training size of 7500 images

This is my model

```
img_size = 50

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu',
                        input_shape=(img_size, img_size, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=2*1e-4),
              metrics=['acc'])
```

```
# Date processing
# All images will be rescaled by 1./255
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=40,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        # This is the target directory
        train_dir,
        target_size=(img_size, img_size),
        batch_size=20,
        class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_dir,
        target_size=(img_size, img_size),
        batch_size=20,
        class_mode='binary')

# Train the Model
history = model.fit(
      train_generator,
      steps_per_epoch=375, #train_sample_size/data_batch_size
      epochs=100,
      validation_data=validation_generator,
      validation_steps=50)
```

[image]

I have tried changing the parameters, such as adding dropout, changing batch size etc.. but still get a really high loss. The loss would be in the negative 20million and just keep increases.